# Перерисовка собственного view при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android, view, виджет, listener

В приложении, при нажатии на одну из двух кнопок, во view (widget) должна отрисовываться точка соответствующего цвета (красный или зеленый) со случайными координатами. Сделал все как в примере. Тем не менее, view никак не реагирует на нажатие кнопок. Еще был такой же пример, но со слушателем модели, который тоже у меня почему-то не работает.

Активность:

```
import ru.srg.app.view.Widget;
import ru.srg.app.model.DotList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private final Random rand = new Random();

    Widget dotView;
    final DotList dotList = new DotList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        dotView = new Widget(this, dotList);

((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout)).addView(dotView, 0);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.redButton)).setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    makeDot(dotList, dotView, Color.RED);
                    dotView.invalidate();
                }
            });

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.grnButton)).setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    makeDot(dotList, dotView, Color.GREEN);
                    dotView.invalidate();
                }
            });
    }
    public void makeDot(DotList dotList, Widget view, int color){
        dotList.addDot(rand.nextInt(900), rand.nextInt(1200), color, rand.nextInt(15));
    }
}
```

Лист:

```
public class DotList
{   
    public ArrayList<Model> dots = new ArrayList<Model>();

    public void addDot(int x, int y, int color, int size){
        dots.add(new Model(x, y, color, size));
    }
}
```

Объект:

```
public class Model
{
    int x, y;
    int color;
    int size;

    public Model(int x, int y, int size, int color){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public int getColor(){
        return color;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }
}
```

Вид:

```
public class Widget extends View
{
    private DotList dotList = new DotList();

    public Widget(Context context, DotList dotList){
        super(context);
        this.dotList = dotList;
        setMinimumWidth(900);
        setMinimumHeight(1200);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, paint);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        for(Model m : dotList.dots){
            paint.setColor(m.getColor());
            canvas.drawCircle(m.getX(), m.getY(), m.getSize(), paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на пример.

Comment: http://src-code.net/slushanie-modeli-programmirovanie-android/

Comment: Воу. А есть ссылка где код не мелким скриншотом, а текстом?..

Comment: Нашел текстом - http://www.developer.am/android/?page=Listening+to+the+Model     Только там без пробелов если разберетесь

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вы вручную переписывали? Может где-то опечатались. Попробуйте код из ссылке выше скопировать и запустить

Comment: Ну не бездумно же переписывал.. Сначала разобрал. Кроме того, сверял с примером раз 10

Comment: Ну... Может что-то не так со списком точек?.. Выведите в логи что-нить из цикла в onDraw